# Spring Framework Join table isn't being populated despite correct entity relationships

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a join table called "excursion_cartitem", when I place an order on the front end, the database table of "excursion_cartitem" doesn't populate. It shows the columns but for the values it says "null".

I have another table called "carts" that will populate, but this is the only one that doesn't. I checked the entity relationships and everything seems to be in order so I am really pulling my hair out because I don't know what to do.

Excursion Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "excursions")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Excursion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "excursion_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "excursion_title")
    private String excursion_title;

    @Column(name = "excursion_price")
    private BigDecimal excursion_price;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String image_URL;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date create_date;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date last_update;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vacation_id")
    private Vacation vacation;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "excursion")
    Set<CartItem> cart_item;

}
```

Cart Item Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart_items")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CartItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_item_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vacation_id")
    private Vacation vacation;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "excursion_cartitem",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cart_item_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "excursion_id")
    )
    Set<Excursion> excursion;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private Cart cart;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date create_date;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date last_update;

}
```

Cart Entity
`

```
package com.jerry.javad288.Entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "order_tracking_number")
    private String orderTrackingNumber;

    @Column(name = "package_price")
    private BigDecimal package_price;

    @Column(name = "party_size")
    private int party_size;

    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusType.CartStatus status = StatusType.CartStatus.pending;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date create_date;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date last_update;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cart")
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems = new HashSet<>();

    public void add(CartItem item){
        if (item != null) {
            if (cartItems == null) {
                cartItems = new HashSet<>();
            }
            cartItems.add(item);
            item.setCart(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Checkout Service Impl

```
@Service
public class CheckoutServiceImpl implements CheckoutService{
    private CartRepository cartRepository;
    @Autowired
    public CheckoutServiceImpl(CartRepository cartRepository)
    {
        this.cartRepository = cartRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PurchaseResponse placeOrder(Purchase purchase) {

        Cart cart = purchase.getCart();

        String orderTrackingNumber = generateOrderTrackingNumber();
        cart.setOrderTrackingNumber(orderTrackingNumber);

        Set<CartItem> cartItems = purchase.getCartItems();
        cartItems.forEach(item -> cart.add(item));

        cart.setStatus(StatusType.CartStatus.ordered);

        Customer customer = purchase.getCustomer();
        customer.add(cart);
        cartRepository.save(cart);

        return new PurchaseResponse(orderTrackingNumber);
    }

    private String generateOrderTrackingNumber() {

        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    }

}
```